# I've updated my apache version, but curl is still showing earlier version

Tags: apache, server, centos6

before some days I've updated the apache version from 2.2.15 to 2.4.34.

When I run the command on my linux centos6 server where is my site hosted:
`httpd -v` it returns

`Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 18 2018 13:25:14`

But when I try using `curl --head mysite.com`
It's showing me different version of apache

`....Other infos....
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
....Other infos....`

Could anyone help me why is that happening.
P.s
I've restarted httpd many times!
My os is Centos 6.10

Answer (score 0):

Per this answer:
https://serverfault.com/questions/698077/does-curl-cache-requests

Try doing `curl --head mysite.com?foo=bar`

Or `curl -v -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" --head mysite.com`

Comment: It's still showing me earlier version of apache. Does that really means that apache's version is 2.2 even though when I type `httpd -v` is showing me 2.4.x?

Comment: What happens if you ssh onto the server and run `curl --head localhost`?

Comment: The DNS server might have it cached. Often DNS information refreshes after 24-48 hours, you could check again tomorrow to see if the version update has been updated.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it tomorrow! Even though this is happening for two days!

Comment: Sounds good. Maybe someone will come along who knows more. To me it seems like your apache version is being cached somewhere and will eventually get refreshed.